# State machines and framework

Tags: php, symfony, state-machine

I'm trying to understand bits and pieces of how frameworks are meant to be used. I'm working on a custom framework i.e. built by using essential components of Symphony2.

So are we understand MVC there is a controller that handles our routing methods. Beside this we have models & repo ( incase of Symphony2 type implementation ).

What i'm confused at is how do i integrate or implement state machines. I would like to know what part goes where.

I would like to use following library,

https://github.com/yohang/Finite

Now my current state is persisted in the table column.

So where do i implement state machine interface, models? Where do initialise state machine, controller?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the model goes, you simply have your model object implement the StatefullInterface.  If, for example, you are using Doctrine 2 then your model object is just a plain php object.  Implement the interface per your link and you are done.

For your state machines I would make custom state machines:

```
class MyStateMachine extends StateMachine
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addState(new State('s1', StateInterface::TYPE_INITIAL));
        $this->addState('s2');
        $this->addState('s3');
        $this->addState(new State('s4', StateInterface::TYPE_FINAL));

        $this->addTransition('t12', 's1', 's2');
        $this->addTransition('t23', 's2', 's3');
        $this->addTransition('t34', 's3', 's4');
        $this->addTransition('t42', 's4', 's2');
```

And then you could create and initialize the object in your controller.  As an alternative use dependency injection and make a factory service.

I suppose you could also embed the state machine directly in your entity.  Probably not a good idea.

The state machine you linked to seems a bit basic.  Only supports one state per object?  I have not checked the code but the transitions also seem pretty primitive.  Make sure it fulfills your needs before investing too much time in it.  I always just create custom machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your entity using a state machine, meaning the state machine will be placed in model layer and rest of the application will interact with it - read its state and invoke transitions.

The entity will provied API to invoke transitions, read its state and enumerate available transitions (like reflection, but with regard to current state). The rest of the application can ask individual instances of the entity what can be done next and show relevant parts of user interface. For example it can show a button to delete an entity which has `delete` transition available in its current state. And when the delete button is clicked, it will invoke the delete transition on given state machine. I found this approach very universal.

Some time ago I created [Smalldb](https://smalldb.org/) framework which implements such state machines. It implements model layer of a web application and lets you define state machines for individual entities and implement their transitions in PHP. It also checks which user is allowed to invoke which transitions and has few nice features like state machine visualization using Graphviz and REST API to directly interact with the state machines from JS (nice for SPA applications).